# MyBatis No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm a beginner with MyBatis, I am using the MyBatis to connect the SQLServer2008, but I always get exception:

Error updating database. Cause:java.sql.SQLException:No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlServer://127.0.0.1:1433;DatabaseName=Test

But I have added the sqljdbc.jar into my Libraries.

Has anyone tried to use mybatis and met the same exception?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have [JTDS jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/) in your classpath. Also, check if your config file should look similar to the following:

```
<configuration>

    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
          <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost(or name of server):1433;databaseName=yourdbname; catalogName=sameasdbname"/>
            <property name="username" value="root"/>
            <property name="password" value="root"/>
            </dataSource>
       </environment>
    </environments>

    <mappers>
       <mapper resource="com/name/data/Contact.xml"/>
    </mappers>

</configuration>
```

If this doesnot resolve it, add the complete stacktrace with configuration